# Why does pcwrite or pcread function in MATLAB change the empty pixel of a pointcloud from [0 0 0] to [0.000000 0.000000 0.000000]?

Tags: matlab, point-cloud-library

I have a pointcloud file "***.ply", whose xyz value is shown as a N*3 matrix. In this xyz matrix, the empty pixel is expressed by [0 0 0]. I pull the ply file directly to the command window and in the edit window, it shows that the empty pixels are still in the forms [0 0 0]. I store this pointcloud to a new pointcloud by pcwrite function and reload the new pointcloud by pcread function. The empty pixels become [0.000000 0.000000 0.000000] and the file size of the new pointcloud is also larger than the original one.
Why does this happen? How can I save 0 as 0 rather than 0.000000 in this case?

I want to save the pointcloud file in the same way as the original file, whose 0 is saved as 0 rather than 0.000000. I think this might be the reason why the file size of the new saved pointcloud file is larger than the original one.

Here is the description of the process:
I pull the original pointcloud file to the command window, it shows that the empty value is in the form [0 0 0]
[image: original pointcloud]

Then I use pcread and pcwrite `sc1 = pcread("Point3D_1.ply");pcwrite(sc1,"Point3D_1compare.ply");` to re-save the same pointcloud. Again, I pull the new file to the command window, it shows that the empty value changes to [0.000000 0.000000 0.000000].
[image: resaved pointcloud]
And the file size of the original file is 5.53MB, the resaved one is 6.79MB.
Here is the original ply file : [ply file google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OQ38GTu3ZCTWdoCVTmAkToxq4w2DOdUL/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Can you post actual code with a very small data set to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: I have posted the pics and data set to illustrate the problem more detailedly. Could you check whether you can help on this? @JamesTursa

Comment: By the way, here is another similar problem. Could anyone help on this?
I have a xyz pointcloud [-0.019937392 0.016235974 0.58587497], whose type is single. I use pcwrite to store the pointcloud and use pcread to reload the same pointcloud. The data becomes [-0.019936999,0.016236000,0.58587497]. And in the variable window, I see that the x data changes from -0.0199374 to -0.0199370. Is this because of the data type single? Here is the code:
`kk2 = single([-0.019937392,0.016235974,0.58587497]);
pcwrite(pointCloud(kk2),"kk2test.ply");
kk2new = pcread("kk2test.ply");`